# Change ConEmu directory to working directory with Git bash

Tags: bash, conemu, msysgit, git-bash

I'm currently using the following to open a Git bash instance:

```
-new_console:"%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

This starts a new tab in the home directory.

I'd like it to start the tab in whatever directory my current tab is in.

Something like the following:

```
-new_console:d:[%CURRENT_DIR%]"%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

So if I'm currently in:

```
> ~/Somedir/SomeOtherDir/
```

Then I open a tab (perhaps with a macro), I'd like the new tab to start in:

```
> ~/Somedir/SomeOtherDir/ (i.e., the same directory)
```

In other words, what command would I place in the following dialog in order to open a new tab which starts in the directory of my current tab? (The command below opens a new tab in the home directory)

[image]

I'm still new to ConEmu (but really enjoying the tabs and customization), so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So, what exactly do you want? What do you have, what do you want to do, what do you want to get?

Comment: You are wrong trying to put your **shell** path in the "-new_console" switch. Executable must be specified separately of course!

Comment: I'd like to open a new tab which starts in the directory of the tab I've opened from. I'll clarify the above. Could elaborate on the wrongness though?

Answer (score 1):

You may run the following in your gitbash prompt

```
ConEmuC -c -new_console sh.exe -l -i
```

But that requires both `ConEmuC.exe` and `sh.exe` are available via `%PATH%`.

And, please note, that the your first command is useless. It can be working only by lucky chance.

```
-new_console:"%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

The `-new_console` does not get shell path (root executable) as argument, it is intended only for specifying [special parameters](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/NewConsole) for new ConEmu's console creation.

Comment: This works in the prompt - is there a way to get this to work as a predefined task? I'd like to have this set as a macro. Copying the above into the pre-defined tasks dialog doesn't appear to work (the new tab opens in the home directory)

Comment: Of course, that must not be working in tasks! They are executed in the ConEmu scope! If you need to run this with macro, why not to use macro? There is `print` GuiMacro function.